# Translating SQL nested query to Django ORM

Tags: sql, django, orm

I do not have much experience with the Django ORM. I have been tasked with creating a Django-based command that would execute a SQL query, but I have no clue how the nested application here would translate into the ORM notation.
Is there a way to do it in a readable way, or is using the 'raw' statement a more reasonable approach? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
update main_connection mc
set test_case_count = 0, test_case_fail_count = 0, status_id = 3
where not mc.test_case_count = (
    select count(*) 
    from test_results_testcase trt 
    where trt.connection_id = mc.id
)
```

Comment: can you share what your models look like

Answer (score 0):

You can create an annotation that counts, then filter by this annotation, and then update

```py
qs1 = MainConection.objects.annotate(test_results_count=Count('test_result_testcase'))
qs2 = qs1.filter(test_results_count=0)
qs2.update(test_case_count=0, test_case_fail_count=0, status_id=3)
```

Those querysets can be done on the same line. 
After an aggregation you can filter by it.\

And the update will change values of the entire queryset after the filter (qs2)

Without see the code, I can't say exactly how do the `Count()`, but the documentation has examples that should help you.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/